# Initialize hex array with int data type in c language

Tags: c

I have define below array in int data types with hexa decimal data.

```
volatile int Send_Data[3] = {0x0H11, 0xAAAC, 0x0DD0};
```

How can I initialize hex array with int data type in c language?

Comment: `0x0H11` is not a valid hex constant

Comment: Apart from an obviously incorrect hex number, what's the problem with the declaration above?

Comment: it was my mistake 0x0H is not element from hexadecimal ..

Comment: `Send_Data` is an `int`-array, its type is `int[3]` to be accurate. There is no such animal as "*hex array*" (at least not in C).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hex array does not exist. Hex is only representation for numbers in computer language (used for programmers).

```
volatile int Send_Data[3] = {1, 2, 3};
```

Comment: Hexadecimal constants are well defined in C, and can be used to initialize or set values for integer types.

Comment: True, but this is not `hex array`. Hex is just representation how number is written to program. `16 = 0x10`. Second is just representation, nothing else. Computer does not calculate in hex world.

Comment: 1, 2, 3 is int by default is signed, I dont see what you provided is not correct.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer don't care for value, just want to point that HEX is jsut representation, nothing else. And I believe you downvoted me.

Comment: Well, i just commented to your answer. Its not me who downvoted. Someone else I guess.

Answer (score 0):

**I would use like this, having a hex table in array.**

```
volatile uint16_t hex16_table[256] = {
0x0000, 0x1021, 0x2042, 0x3063, 0x4084, 0x50a5, 0x60c6, 0x70e7 };
```

I guess this is what your looking for.